# Do film industries outside India use intervals/Intermission?

Tags: indian-cinema

I have seen classic English movies with intervals/Intermission. Current Indian movie industries (Bollywood and others) use intervals and theaters introduce intervals in current English films by interrupting them. Are there other film industries who use intervals?

I am not asking about just theater practices. Movies often change tone after the interval so movie reviews compare both "halves". For example the first half of a movie may evoke laughter all the time while the second half is dead serious.

Comment: Oh. Well, then this seems more related to the films and the cinemas showing them and not so much the respective film industries of the countries, it seems.

Comment: A quick google suggests that intermissions are [ubiquitous in Indian cinema/s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermission) but surprisingly rare elsewhere.

Comment: Also, it's a bit of a cop-out given the cultural similarities but they're apparently similarly common in Pakistani cinemas.

Comment: I remember that the original run of "Dances with Wolves" had an intermission at least in Germany - not sure if this was actually intended by the filmmakers (also I know a few small arthouse cinemas with integrated bars that stop movies halfway to sell drinks, but that is probably not what you are asking).

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Movies change tone after the intermission. Every minute of the first half may be hilarious while the second half is dead serious. Movie reviews always compare the "halves".

Comment: Cinemas here tend to do it primarily based on length. Basically if a movie's 2.5 hours long it'll probably have a 10 minute break in the middle.

Comment: @aitchnyu That's interesting, though. But this then seems to be the film itself having an intermission and *not* the cinema introducing it. There should be made a difference between the two approaches.

Comment: British cinemas (at least mainstream multiplexes) absolutely do not do intervals. Interestingly though, one of the main reasons given for not doing so (patrons might sneak into other films) isn't something that concerns most owners. Those I've spoken to couldn't really care less if you watch two or even three films.

Comment: Well he said change tone and compare "halves" as in they are almost different. If you would like a modern take on this just watch "The Equalizer (2014)" , could have been a perfect or seminal tough guy flick. Its a 2 hr movie and after the first hr it may as well have been directed by the lighting manger. Brilliant to complete rubbish in an almost exact intermission split.

Comment: Interval also give theatres time to sell there high prize poor food

Comment: I remember it happening in the 60s/70s in the UK, but haven't been to a movie since with an interval. Theatres still do, not movies.

Comment: The epic movie, Ben-Hur (1959 w/Charlton Heston, made and released in the US), not only had an intermission, it had an overture at the beginning of each half (which is a real treat since the movie score was written by the fabulous composer Miklos Rosza!)

Comment: It's not surprisingly rare when you consider that Indian films are nearly always 3 hours long or longer and the average American film is 1.5-2 hours...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Interval/Intermission were originated from west but its India which is still sticking with it.

> Intermissions in early films had a practical purpose: they were needed
>   to facilitate the changing of reels. When Les Amours de la reine
>   Élisabeth (Queen Elizabeth), starring Sarah Bernhardt, opened on July
>   12, 1912, in the Lyceum Theatre in New York City, the four reel film
>   was shown in four acts, with an intermission between each reel change.
>   - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermission#Films)

But with technology improvement this reel change process was eliminated so does intervals/intermission. But India still use them and they even place them in middle of foreign film too but they mostly repeat one scene before and after interval as this film didn't keep appropriate position for interval as Bollywood film do.

Form [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermission#Films)

> Despite the phasing out of intermissions in the West, they have
>   remained prevalent in India, and especially with Bollywood films.
>   There is a mass reluctance to abolish intermissions as they bring a
>   large revenue to cinemas through customers buying snacks during these
>   periods.
>
> Indian films are also typically longer compared to films from other
>   parts of the world. In 2011, a Bollywood film, Dhobi Ghat, was
>   released without an intermission and was cited as a first in Indian
>   cinema. Forced intermissions are common during screenings of western
>   films in India.

But one point to be noted here that Dhobi Ghat was only 95 minute longer, that might be the reason for removing interval.

But there are exception in Hollywood too, they also have films with interval, latest example is Hateful Eight, from [cinemablend.com](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/Quentin-Tarantino-Have-Two-Versions-Hateful-Eight-Theaters-87837.html) :

> So there will be two versions of The Hateful Eight hitting screens
>   this December. The "roadshow" cut, which hits theaters first, will
>   play in 70mm, but it will also be the longer, idealized version of the
>   film. According to Tarantino, this version will have both an overture
>   and an intermission to contend with. It will be approximately
>   six-and-a-half minutes longer than the other, longer still if you
>   count the intermission, and the whole shebang will clock in at just
>   over three hours.

Same Wikipedia link[*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermission#Films) also list other Hollywood film with intermission/interval but they have warning of "citation needed", so I am excluding them from answer.

As per [scoopwhoop.com](http://www.scoopwhoop.com/Why-do-Indian-movies-have-intervals-theory/)

> Hollywood films are written keeping the 'three-act structure' in mind.
>   They set up the plot, introduce the conflict and then resolve it. And
>   there is no point to have a break midway.
>   [image]
>
> But Bollywood films are written differently. We follow a different
>   structure. In the first half, the characters and the plot is
>   introduced. It is here when we are introduced with the conflict as
>   well.  The interval point acts as a cliffhanger. It keeps the audience
>   hooked for the second half.
>
> In fact, the interval point can be termed as a mini-climax which is of
>   lesser intensity than the film's actual climax.