# Do Indian movies screened outside India, have intervals as well?

Tags: indian-cinema

Do American movie theaters really have the intermission for Indian movies or do they skip it?

Like: Indian movie theater do have an intermission for [Baahubali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baahubali:_The_Beginning). But do US theaters have an interval for the same movie as well?

My Question is different from this [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/51695/do-film-industries-outside-india-use-intervals-intermission). I am not asking whether film industries outside India use intermissions. My question is about intermission taken for Indian movies by US theaters.

Comment: Question can be really understand by an audiences who saw Indian movie in US.

Comment: The title says "outside India", but the question asks about American cinema.  Are you wanting an answer specific to cinema screenings in the U.S., or will any country screening an Indian/Bollywood film do?

Comment: How's your question different from the other?

Comment: @Luciano @S S  He's asking if Indian movies outside of India include the interval, where the other question was asking whether non-Indian movies have intervals.  Completely different question.

Comment: @aryxus can you edit my question, so people will here understand & remove **duplicate** tag.

Comment: @close-voters  This question is not asking whether film industries outside India use intermissions or not. **This is about intermission taken for Indian movies by US theaters.**

Comment: @DhanrajKumar: Looks like A J took care of it.  However, I thought it was pretty clear already. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the US we do have intervals for Indian movies that last about 20 minutes. I don't have a reference apart from seeing a bunch of Indian Movies in NY, NJ, WA and CA states.

However there is no hard and fast rule: this completely depends on the discretion of the owner of the theatre and could change any day and in any theatre.

And of course, this cannot be extended to other countries as well.

Comment: In Seattle and many other places I've watched Indian movies, they show the 'interval' or 'intermission' title, but do NOT pause the movie, unfortunately.  I've seen a few dozen over the past years in and around Washington State and Utah, and none have had the actual intermission.